# Jquery tabs always render without css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm putting together a page for a school and it contains `jquery` tabs, with a bit of style.

The page works perfectly in `dreamweaver`, but when I upload it to the page the tabs will only very rarely render with styles.

They appear to just not take the `css` or `js`, so I experimented with forcing it to render after the entire page loads, but it could very well be that it needs to render **BEFORE** the page loads. I know it works because occasionally i see them as tabs, and then after a reload they disappear and don't come back till I reload another 20 times.

Here are a few options of the js I've used:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("div.Tabs1").tabs();
});
```

and

```
$("div.Tabs1").tabs();
```

etc.

I've tried bind, load etc. and it just wont render the tabs consistently.

Should I be rendering before or after the page load?

Annoyingly it will render some other tabs in the UI of the page I'm tweaking  in my style. (I'm putting the page into a learning management system). This works consistently. It just doesn't like mine.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: Can you enter screen shots and also check path of the css and js are correct or not.

Comment: Why are you using, `$(window).load`? Why not `$(document).ready`? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it looks like you're setting up tabs for multiple divs with `$("div.Tabs1").tabs();`.  In the jQuery UI Tabs tutorial, they're selecting the only element with id "tabs", using `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` https://jqueryui.com/tabs/